# How can I know if a string have the value of zero with regex?

Tags: regex

I want to validate a string and if this has the value of zero give a message to the user to change the value.

Now I have the validation for a number different of zero and is working

```
(?!^0*$)(?!^0*\.0*$)^\d{1,14}(\.\d{2,2})$
```

But I wonder if I can make a regex to know if the string has the value of zero.

Comment: what language? are you sure regex is required?

Comment: I suggest not doing this with a regex, or coming up with your own solution.  This is a solved problem.  Ask the language that you're using to evaluate the string.

Comment: What's considered zero? `0`, `0.0`, `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001`, `0.`, `.0`?

Comment: If you want to fail zero value, your regex does it. Or, use a bit leaner version, `^(?!0*(?:\.0*)?$)\d{1,14}\.\d{2}$`.

Comment: @depperm I am using visual Basic

Comment: So what is your code? What output do you obtain? What do you expect?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I wish it was the value of zero but if this is not possible in regex we could say that zero can be 0, 0.0 or 0.00 in this specific case

Comment: Why not do something like `If Convert.toDecimal(myInput.Text) = 0.0 Then /* show warning */ End If)`?

Comment: It depends on what you would consider zero. You could use for example `^0+(?:\.0+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/4F8SIZ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match zero for the values `0` `0.0` or `0.00` you could use

```
^0+(?:\.0+)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `0+` Match 1 or more zeroes
- `(?:\.0+)?` Optionally match `.` and 1 or more zeroes
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4F8SIZ/1/)